# How to Make calculator With out if else?

Tags: python, if-statement, calculator, python-3.9

I tried to make a calculator in python with out if else statements . i can't find how to fix a issue in present code

```
def add(n1, n2):
return n1+n2
def sub(n1, n2):
    return n1-n2
def mul(n1, n2):
    return n1*n2
def div(n1, n2):
    return n1/n2
def pow(n1, n2):
    return n1^n2
operations_and_functions= {
    "+":"add",
    "-":"sub",
    "*":"mul",
    "/":"div",
    "^":"pow",
}
num1 = int(input("What is your first number=> "))
num2 = int(input("What is your second number=> "))
for operations in operations_and_functions:
    print(operations)
***operation = str(input("What operation do you want to do=> "))
calculation = operations_and_functions[operation](num1,num2)***
answer = calculation(num1,num2)
print(f"{num1} {calculation} {num2} is equal to {answer}")
```

I can't convert this code" [operations_and_functionsoperation" into "add(num1,num2)"

Comment: Shouldn't the operation functions not be strings?

Comment: Don't you want the actual functions in your dictionary, `"+":add,` etc. instead of the *names* of the functions?

Comment: `n1^n2` does not do what you think does. `n1**n2` is what you are looking for

Answer (score 2):

The values of your `dict` should be the functions themselves, not strings. Also, don't call the result again:

```
from operator import add, sub, mul, truediv, pow

operations_and_functions= {
    "+": add,
    "-": sub,
    "*": mul,
    "/": truediv,
    "^": pow,
}
num1 = 3
num2 = 5
operations_and_functions["+"](num1,num2)
# 8
operations_and_functions["-"](num1,num2)
# -2
operations_and_functions["*"](num1,num2)
# 15
operations_and_functions["/"](num1,num2)
# 0.6
operations_and_functions["^"](num1,num2)
# 243
```

You can of course define the functions yourself, as you did. One fix there:

```
def pow(n1, n2):
    return n1**n2
```

In Python, `^` is the bitwise XOR operator.

Comment: Thankyou For Answering My Doubt

Comment: `pow` is already a builtin function: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow